# IndentationError in maya console but can't find any indentation error to fix

Tags: python, indentation, maya

I'm making a rigging tool/following a tutorial in Maya and for some reason I'm getting an unexpected indent error.  I've gone through it multiple times replacing all white space with either spaces or tabs to no avail.

```
import os

try:
    riggingToolRoot = os.environ["RIGGING_TOOL_ROOT"]
except:
    print "RIGGING_TOOL_ROOT environment variable not correctly configured"
else:
    import sys
    print riggingToolRoot
    path = riggingToolRoot + "/Modules"

    if not path in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

    import System.blueprint_UI as blueprint_UI
    reload(blueprint_UI)

    UI = blueprint_UI.Blueprint_UI()
```

Apparently "    import System.blueprint_UI as blueprint_UI" is the offending
line and it only flagged up after the latest changes to blueprint_UI.py.  I've included the code from that too if that's any use.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import System.utils as utils
reload(utils)

class Blueprint_UI:
    def __init__(self):
        # Store UI elements in a dictionary.
        self.UIElements = {}

        if cmds.window("blueprint_UI_window", exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI("blueprint_UI_window")

        windowWidth = 400
        windowHeight = 598

        self.UIElements["window"] = cmds.window("blueprint_UI_window", width=windowWidth, height=windowHeight, title="Blueprint Module UI", sizeable=False)

        self.UIElements["topLevelColumn"] = cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True, columnAlign="center")

        # Setup tabs
        tabHeight = 500
        self.UIElements["tabs"] = cmds.tabLayout(height=tabHeight, innerMarginWidth=5, innerMarginHeight=5)

        tabWidth = cmds.tabLayout(self.UIElements["tabs"], q=True, width=True)
        self.scrollWidth = tabWidth - 40

        self.initialiseModuleTab(tabHeight,tabWidth)

        cmds.tabLayout(self.UIElements["tabs"], edit=True, tabLabelIndex=([1, "Modules"]))


        # Display window
        cmds.showWindow( self.UIElements["window"] )

    def initialiseModuleTab(self, tabHeight, tabWidth):
        scrollHeight = tabHeight # temp value

        self.UIElements["moduleColumn"] = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True, rs=3)

        self.UIElements["moduleFrameLayout"] = cmds.frameLayout(height=scrollHeight, collapsable=False, borderVisible=False, labelVisible=False)

        self.UIElements["moduleList_Scroll"] = cmds.scrollLayout(hst=0)

        self.UIElements["moduleList_Column"] = cmds.columnLayout(columnWidth = self.scrollWidth, adj=True, rs=2)

        # First separator
        cmds.separator()

        for module in utils.findAllModules("Modules/Blueprint"):
            print module
```

Comment: You have an indentation issue on the first `try` statement. Moreover, what's the point of `else` after `except`? If you wish to import `sys` in case `riggingToolRoot = os.environ["RIGGING_TOOL_ROOT"]` fails, you should add it to `except`.

Comment: My apologies, that indent error was me copying it into this - I've edited it to reflect how it actually looks.
The except is just to catch it if the environment file isn't setup, otherwise nothing past that would work for the tool.

Comment: Then you don't need `else`. Just make the imports.

Comment: Just tried that and the same line `UI = blueprint_UI.Blueprint_UI()` is flagging up an indent error.

Comment: Check if you're mixing spaces and tabs. That could be a cause.

Comment: Done that a few times but just tried again there and the error changed from that line to `import System.blueprint_UI as blueprint_UI`